# How to change the auto completion button in squeak?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

is there a way to change the shortcut to invoke auto completion in the squeak vm (standard is `tab`)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I assume you use OCompletion or ECompletion)

The only way to change this currently is to change the code.

```
OController>>handleKeystrokeBefore: kbEvent editor: theEditor 
    "I return a boolean. true when I have handled the event and no futher processing is needed by the caller."
    | keyValue ctrl cmd down tab colon alphanum del esc enter up |
    self editor: theEditor.
    self setModel: theEditor model.
    keyValue := kbEvent keyValue.
    ctrl := kbEvent controlKeyPressed.
    cmd := kbEvent commandKeyPressed.
    down := keyValue = 31.
    up := keyValue = 30.
    tab := kbEvent keyCharacter = Character tab. "<-- change this to your desired key"
    enter := kbEvent keyCharacter = Character cr.  
    colon := kbEvent keyCharacter = $:.
    alphanum := kbEvent keyCharacter isAlphaNumeric.
    "..."
```

Or, when you only use ECompletion

```
ECController>>handleKeystrokeBefore: aKeyboardEvent editor: anEditor 
    "I return a boolean. true when I have handled the event and no futher processing is needed by the caller."

    | theEditor keyValue controlKeyPressed isSpaceKey |
    self editor: anEditor. 
    theEditor := self editor.
    self setModel: theEditor model.
    keyValue := aKeyboardEvent keyValue.
    controlKeyPressed := aKeyboardEvent controlKeyPressed.
    isSpaceKey := #(0 32 ) includes: keyValue.
    "Ctrl-Space or Tab for open"
    self isMenuOpen
        ifFalse: [(isSpaceKey & controlKeyPressed
                    or: [keyValue = 9 "            <-- change this to your desired key"
                            and: [theEditor isCaretBehindChar
                                    and: [controlKeyPressed not]]])
    "..."
```